# sql query not working after using mysql_real_esacape_string

Tags: php, sql

This Piece Of Code Is Not Working :

```
$un_name=$_POST[name];
$un_idno=$_POST[idno];
$un_hostel=$_POST[hostel];
$un_mode=$_POST[mode];
$un_date=$_POST[date];  
$un_time=$_POST[time];
$un_tfno=$_POST[tfno];
$un_contact=$_POST[contact];

$sa_name=mysql_real_escape_string ($un_name);   
$sa_idno=mysql_real_escape_string ($un_idno);
$sa_hostel=mysql_real_escape_string ($un_hostel);
$sa_mode=mysql_real_escape_string ($un_mode);
$sa_date=mysql_real_escape_string ($un_date);
$sa_time=mysql_real_escape_string ($un_time);
$sa_tfno=mysql_real_escape_string ($un_tfno);
$sa_contact=mysql_real_escape_string ($un_contact);

$sql="INSERT INTO cabs (NAME,IDNO,HOSTEL,MODE,DATE,TIME,TFNO,CONTACT)
VALUES
('$sa_name','$sa_idno','$sa_hostel','$sa_mode','$sa_date','$sa_time','$sa_tfno','$sa_contact')";
```

While the same code when normally inserted works .....

```
$sql="INSERT INTO cabs (NAME,IDNO,HOSTEL,MODE,DATE,TIME,TFNO,CONTACT)
VALUES
 ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[idno]','$_POST[hostel]','$_POST[mode]','$_POST[date]','$_POST[time]','$_POST[tfno]','$_POST[contact]')";
```

I was just trying my first steps to prevent **sql injection**..but there seems to be some problem....

**Note : My host doesnt seem to support mysqli so that's why i had to use msql which is deprecated.**

Comment: Does your host support PDO?

Comment: Does your PHP have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled? That would escape the `$_POST` variables automatically, and escaping it again in your code would cause problems.

Comment: yea magic quote is enabled

Comment: Can you turn it off? There's a reason it has been removed from recent PHP versions, it makes it really difficult to process parameters cleanly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");//connection string
$sa_name=mysql_real_escape_string($con,$un_name);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Your arguments are correct for `mysqli_real_escape_string`. The `mysql` functions take the connection argument _after_ all the other arguments, and it's optional.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use PDO instead?

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "dbname";

$link = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));      

$foo_var = 3;

$query_result = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM modules
                                WHERE id = :foo
                                LIMIT 1");
$query_result->bindValue(":foo", $foo_var);
$query_result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$query_result->execute();

while($row = $query_result->fetch()) {

    return $row;
}
```

Comment: i dont understand pdo

Comment: @PRP Is that really a valid excuse? If you don't understand it, learn it. If you can't, you're in the wrong line of work.